# Every positive integer $n$ has at least as many divisors of the form $4k + 1$ as divisors of the form $4k + 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Provided that $n$ is a positive integer, how do we prove it has at least as many divisors of the form $4k+1$ as divisors of the form $4k+3$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$? What I've tried is assuming that the statement holds for some $m$ and then proving it holds for all $mp$, where $p$ is prime. This doesn't seem to get us far, since it's hard to relate divisors of $m$ with $mp$. Also, note that if we take the product of two numbers of the form $4k + 1$ or two numbers of the form $4k+3$, we get a number of the form $4k + 1$, and if we take the product of a number of the form $4k+1$ and a number of the form $4k+3$, we get a number of the form $4k+3$. I think this fact may be useful.

Comment: Hint:  Suppose $n=m\times k$ with $1<m,k$ and $\gcd(m,k)=1$.  If the claim is true for $m,k$, can you deduce it for $n$?

Comment: Another strategy can be considering the "extreme case" n=p^k where p is a prime of the form 4k+3 and showing that the claim is true

Comment: Let $\chi(d)$ be the function that takes the value $0$ if $d$ is even, takes the value $1$ if $d$ is of the form $4k+1$, and takes the value $-1$ if $d$ is of the form $4k+3$. Then $\sum_{d\mid n} \chi(d)$ is directly relevant to your question. Can you show that $\chi$ is multiplicative and hence this sum is a multiplicative function of $n$? That should reduce the problem to showing it for prime powers.

Comment: Or, do it directly: suppose it has $A$ primes of the form $4k+1$ and $B$ primes of the form $4k+3$, and $C$ primes of the form $2$. How many divisors are of the form $4k+1$? $4k+3$?

Comment: Just shooting here.  Lets suppos $n = 2^w\prod q_i^{n_i}\prod p_j^{m_j}$ is the prime factorization were $q$ are primes of the form $4k+1$ and $p$ are primes of the form $4k+3$. The factors of the form $4k+3$ are $\{\prod q_i^{a_i}\prod p_j^{s_j}|a_i\le n_i; s_ji\le m_j\sum s_i$ is odd$\}$ and the factors of the form $4k+1$ are $\{\prod q_i^{a_i}\prod p_j^{s_j}|a_i\le n_i; s_ji\le m_j\sum s_i$ is even$\}$.  You can put this in counting order.  As every odd sum is preceded immediately by an even sum the result should follow.

Comment: @fleablood It's a bit trickier than just a simple comparison (which is my interpretation of "put this in counting order"). It eventually boils down to $ \sum { M \choose 2s } \geq \sum { M \choose 2s+1 } $, where $ M = \sum m_j$. $\quad$ Note that the exact values of $p_j$ do not matter, which is why I phrased my comment as just $A / B / C$.

Comment: I am having trouble finding that $253=11*23$ has as many divisors of the two forms.

Comment: @CalvinLin essentially for every $Qp_m^{2a_m+1}$ of the form $4k+3$ then $Qp_m^{2a_m}$ is of form $4k+1$.  The trouble of course could be that $Qp_n^{2a_n+}p_m^{2a_m}\ne Qp_n^{2a_n}p_m^{2a_m+1}$ would be two factors of the form $4k+3$ and my reducing algorithm would result in the same $Qp_n^{2a_n}p_m^{2a_m}$.  I figure we can somehow put these divisors in order of there primes and only reserve the higher primes to odd powers for when we need them.  That's what I meant by "counting order".  .....

Comment: ... "counting order" cont. If we consider the divisor $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}.....p_m^{a_m}p_{m+1}^{a_{m+1}}....$ where $a_m$ is the *last* odd power then we map it to the divisor $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}.....p_m^{a_m-1}$. Hmm... but then we have ambiguity if $a_m=1$ *and* $a_{m-1}$ is even *and* $p_m$ is of form $4k+3$. So I'll some cleverer counting algorithm. I'm sure of two things.  1) it can be done and ii) I'm too lazy to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s prove the following statement: if a positive integer $n$ has a prime of the form $4k+3$ in the odd power in its prime factorization then $n$ has as many divisors of the form $4k+1$ as of the form $4k+3$, otherwise $n$ has more divisors of the form $4k+1$ than of the form $4k+3$.

Consider prime decomposition of the number $n$. The primes fall into three categories: of the from $4k+1$, of the form $4k+3$, number $2$ (not all of them can be present for a given $n$, of course). The third category is completely irrelevant for our problem since if a divisor contains a factor $2^i$ it is not of the form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$. So we assume that $n$ is odd.

Let $n$ have a factor $q^b$ in its prime factorization where $q$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$ and $b$ is odd. Then let us build a bijection between all the divisors of $n$ of the form $4k+1$ and of the form $4k+3$. Any divisor of $n$ that contains $q^i$ where $i$ is even will be corresponded to a divisor containing $q^{i+1}$. (Note that $i+1\leq b$ since $b$ is odd.) All the divisors are split into pairs where one divisor is of the form $4k+1$ and another is of the form $4k+3$. Hence their quantities are equal.

If all the divisors of $n$ of the form $4k+3$ are raised to even powers then the following procedure can be applied. Let $q_1, q_2, …, q_m$ be all the prime divisors of the form $4k+3$. We can split almost all divisors of $n$ the same way as in the previous paragraph with respect to $q_1$ except the divisors containing $q_1$ raised to the maximum power. We will try to split these divisors with respect to $q_2$ the same way. We will get that all the divisors split in pairs except a group of divisors containing all $q_i$ raised to their maximum powers. These powers are all even. So these numbers are all of the form $4k+1$. And there is at least one of them. This finishes the proof.

——————————————————————

**Note $1.$** “a positive integer $n$ has a prime of the form $4k+3$ in the odd power in its prime factorization” is the same condition as “$n$ can’t be presented as a sum of two squares of integer numbers”.

**Note $2.$** Another way of proof also comes to mind. I will sketch it here. Let $n$ be odd. If $n$ is of the form $4k+3$ then all its divisors are split into pairs $(a,b)$ where $ab=n$ ($a\neq b$ since $4k+3$ is never a square). In each pair one of the divisors is of the form $4k+1$ and another is of the form $4k+3$.

If $n$ is of the form $4k+1$ and it has $q^b$ in its prime factorization where $q$ is of the form $4k+3$ and $b$ is odd then $n/q^b$ is of the form $4k+3$ and previous method of splitting into pairs works. Multiplying by $q^i, i\leq b$ doesn’t change anything.

Finally, if $n$ is of the form $4k+1$ and all the primes of the form $4k+3$ in its factorization are raised to an even power then one can show that quantity of the divisors of the form $4k+1$ is greater.