Find number of divisor of $n=3^{5}\cdot 5^{7}\cdot 7^{9}$ which are of the form $4k+1$, $n\geq 0$

Find number of divisor of $n=3^{5}\cdot 5^{7}\cdot 7^{9}$ which are of the form $4k+1$, $k\geq 0$

My solution: Total number of divisor of $n$ are $(5+1)(7+1)(9+1)=480$
All the divisor can be of the form $4k,4k+1,4k+1,4k+3$
But as $n$ is odd so all the divisor will be of the form either $4n+1$ or $4n+3$ so total divisor will be of the form $4n+1=240$ which matches with the answer

Find total number of divisor of $n=(10)^{10}\cdot (11)^{11}\cdot (13)^{13}$ of the form $4k+1$, $k\geq 0$

My solution Total number of divisor $(10+1)(10+1)(11+1)(13+1)=20328$
Number of even divisor $(10)(11)(12)(14)=18480$
So total number of odd divisor $20328-18480=1848$
So number of odd divisor of the form $4k+1$ is $924$ which matches with the answer given.
My doubt: Is there any example where this method fails? Also is there other method to solve above two problems?

Are you trying to say the number of divisors of the form $4k+1$ is the same as number of divisors of the form $4k+3$? In general, it is not true. A counterexample is $n=5$. If $n$ has at least one prime of the form $4k+3$ with odd power then it's true. See here:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4860052/1231540

I disagree with your reasoning in the two problems, because you are assuming that you can always apply the $~1/2~$ scalar.  The approach works only because at least one of the critical bases has an even number of exponent choices.
For the first problem:
There are $~6,8,~$ and $~10~$ choices for the exponents assigned to $~3,5,~$ and $~7,~$ respectively.
Since $~5 \equiv 1 \pmod{4},~$ the exponent assigned to $~5~$ is irrelevant.
For the other two bases, $~3,~$ and $~7,~$ each of which is $~\equiv -1 \pmod{4},~$ the sum of the exponents assigned to each must be even.
The simplest way of attacking this is that for each choice of an exponent assigned to the $~3,~$ exactly half of the possible exponents assigned to the $~7~$ are suitable.
This approach explains, in a clearer detail, why half of the possibilities are satisfactory.

The exact same approach is at work in the 2nd problem.  For example, $~11,~$ which is the critical base, has an even number of choices, of which 1/2 are suitable.
To find a scenario where the approach does not work, change the first problem to $~3^6 \times 5^7 \times 7^{10}.~$
Then, the number of [3::7] exponent choices is $~7~ \times 11,~$ and you have to manually count.
In such a circumstance, for each odd exponent assigned to the $~3,~$ there would be $~5~$ satisfactory exponents that could be assigned to the $~7.~$
For each even exponent assigned to the $~3,~$ there would be $~6~$ satisfactory exponents that could be assigned to the $~7.~$
So of the $~77~$ possible [3::7] exponent choices, the number of satisfactory choices is
$$[ ~3 \times 5~] + [ ~4 \times 6 ~] = 39.$$
So, for this problem, although the number of [3::5::7] exponent choices is an even number, the number of satisfactory exponent choices is not 1/2 of the total.

Further justification is definitely needed.  The reason it works in the first case is because $n\equiv3\pmod4$.  If $u$ and $v$ are factors of $n$ such that $n=uv$, if $u\equiv1\pmod4$, then $v\equiv3\pmod4$ and vice versa.  Therefore, exactly half of the factors are equivalent to $1\pmod4$.  In the second problem, the same is true of $\frac{n}{2^{10}}$.
